# Custom Server Control in ASP.NET and C# -

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-server-controls, htmltextwriter

I've got a aspx and aspx.cs file with some components. Now I want to reuse parts of that page in another page. My approach would be to pull out the duplicate part into a WebServerControl.

So before I waste more time yahoogling, is that even the right idea and if so, is there a way to use parts of the aspx file rather than doing it tediously in `RenderContents` with the `HtmlTextWriter`, `WriteBeginTag`, `WriteAttribute` and so on. That looks like a mess for complicated layout and sizeable amounts of controls.

What's the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.

The main driving factor is that if you need to reuse your control in multiple web applications, you should go with a `Custom Control` (.cs in C#).

Else, if you only intend to reuse your control in one web application, choose a `User Control` (.ascx).

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) MSDN article is a good starting point.

UPDATE (since OP asked further details):

To embed JavaScript for a custom control, a common approach is

```
var initializeScript = string.Format("MyNamespace.initialize('{0}', {1});", ClientID, myScriptString);
Attributes.Add("onmouseover", initializeScript);
```

Suggest to write JavaScript code in a js file and not in .cs since the latter is a nightmare to maintain and debug. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK how about if the user control contains some javascript, can I call that from the embedding page?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is bundle the items into a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx). This will allow you to design the control by using existing .NET controls rather than rendering everything out from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create an [ASP.NET Web User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx)

**Taken from MSDN:**

> An ASP.NET Web user control is similar to a complete ASP.NET Web page
>   (.aspx file), with both a user interface page and code. You create the
>   user control in much the same way you create an ASP.NET page and then
>   add the markup and child controls that you need. A user control can
>   include code to manipulate its contents like a page can, including
>   performing tasks such as data binding.